# How to make GValue automatically cleanup gchar*s

Tags: c, glib

I want my `GValue` to contain and own a dynamic string (`gchar*`). It should clean up the string (`gchar*`) on termination.

I'm trying to use a `Boxed Type`, but I can't get it to work.

This is what I've got so far:

```
GType boxedString = g_boxed_type_register_static (
                   "boxedString", boxed_copy, boxed_free);

GValue * val = g_new0(GValue, 1);
g_value_init (val, boxedString);
g_value_take_string (val, g_strdup ("hello"));
```

But that throws a `g_value_take_string: assertion 'G_VALUE_HOLDS_STRING (value)' failed`.

#### What I've tried and didn't work

- Use `g_value_take_string`:  Doesn't work. String is not owned and therefore not freed.

```
GValue * val = g_new0(GValue, 1);
g_value_init (val, G_TYPE_STRING);
g_value_take_string (val, g_strdup ("hello"));
```

- Use `G_TYPE_STRING`: Doesn't work. String is not owned and therefore not freed.

#### Other options:

- If there would be a derivative of `GObject`, that can hold a pointer and a destruction method, it would work. But I can't find any type that allows it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string won’t be freed until you call `g_value_unset()`.

```c
GValue *val = g_new0 (GValue, 1);  // you can also stack-allocate it to avoid a call to g_new0()
g_value_init (val, G_TYPE_STRING);
g_value_set_string (val, "hello");
// or g_value_take_string (val, g_strdup ("hello"));

…

g_value_unset (val);
g_free (val);
```